# Understanding where to begin with batch processing on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I have a set of calculations that needs to run in a batch, and the workload is easily parallelized across machines. The work to be done is already done within a Docker container. I'm trying to understand the easiest way for me to run this workload in a highly parallel way on AWS. However, in trying to figure out where to begin I'm having trouble finding the right entrypoint. I read about AWS Batch and AWS Fargate, but each time I try to go down one of those paths to learn about them in more detail, more AWS services start popping up (Lamdas,  Step Functions, ECS, AutoScaling groups), with each article having a different combination. Furthermore, I start thinking about the problem as a Batch vs Fargate problem, and then I find another article that talks about Batch + Fargate, or X + ECS + ....

I'm having trouble finding the appropriate introduction to the choices so I can get started with setting something up and getting some experience. Any pointers on which direction I might go or some resources for me to look at?

Comment: Hey @gammapoint :) how do you want to trigger this workload? That will define this much easier - do you want to trigger it automatically? Manually? By parallel, do you mean something that scales? Scales in response to HTTP requests? Queue messages?

Comment: Thanks, @ErmiyaEskandary. Triggering it manually or automatically (say, when data is put into an S3 bucket, messages are placed into the SQS queue, etc.) are both fine. I would be the one putting the messages into the queue or data in S3, so it's really manual for me at that level anyway. For concreteness we can say when data shows up in an S3 bucket. By scales I mean more along the lines of the amount of work (the unit of work could be encoded in the queue messages). It's more of a scientific / ML computation and there is are no HTTP requests to speak of. Happy to clarify further if it helps.

Comment: have you gone through the AWS Batch getting started docs? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/Batch_GetStarted.html

Comment: If I knew how to do something simple like deposit a CSV with names into an S3 bucket, and then a bunch of Docker containers would be spun up (say, a container per 100 names), with each Docker container writing 'Hello {name}' for each name in its workload of 100 to S3, that would be a similar problem.

Comment: @kielni, no I haven't, though that's sort of the motivation for my question. In other words, do Iook at intro docs for Batch, Fargate, ECS, etc? If Batch is a good place to start I can look there.

Comment: Considering you say ML computation - do any of the inbuilt AWS services achieve what you want to? Click under "Machine Learning" on this page https://aws.amazon.com/products/

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I don't think so, though I'm not entirely sure. In any case, I have other use cases for which I would want to do the generic thing I'm describing here that definitely wouldn't fall under AWS ML tools, so I'm still interested in the general question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS containers services team member here. Your question triggers all my button cause I have been working on a deliverable to address some of this confusion ("where do I start with xyz?"). I can try to answer your question briefly here but if you want to read more (perhaps way more than you'd need feel free to contact me offline (mreferre at amazon dot com will work).

First and foremost it's not a Vs but it's an AND. Think of all these products you mention being distributed at different layers of the stack (this is a draft visual in the deliverable):

[image: stack]

Fargate represents capacity (where your container is running), ECS represents a core containers orchestrator and Batch is one of the provisioners on top of the container orchestrator. Lambda is something separate and that live on its own. The options for your specific use case seem to be:

- Lambda
- ECS/Fargate
- Batch/ECS/Fargate
- Step Functions/ECS/Fargate (this one is outside of analysis and you don't see it in my visual - wondering if I should add it).

As others have hinted you probably want to use Lambda if your model is event-driven (e.g. if you want to fire up a dedicated function for every event like a new file uploaded to S3).

You probably do not want to use a naked ECS/Fargate solution because it would require more work to deal with the triggering and the scheduling of your batch jobs.

You probably want to use either Batch or Step Functions to schedule jobs on ECS/Fargate. I'd argue SF is good if you have basic workflows that you need to deal with and Batch if you need to manage complex jobs at scale. Perhaps [this 35 mins presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hq5cUQ1rLMM) that I did last year can provide a bit more background on these Batch Vs SF differences.

Let me know if you have any additional questions because this discussion is super useful for the positioning I am trying to build.

Comment: Appreciate all the detail, Massimo. Looks like my google-fu isn't too bad as I already had the presentation of yours at the top of my to watch list on this topic :) I'll definitely carve out some time to watch it now. Our code is already parallelized over many, many lambdas but I assume that's not cost-efficient. I also discovered some of the AWS tutorials like this one: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/run-batch-jobs-at-scale-with-ec2-spot/. Here Batch is used with spot, which sounds good as well but doesn't mention ECS/Fargate. Is this a Vs or an AND?

Comment: I should comment that part of the issue is not just getting something up and working. Historically (for other projects) I have spun up a fixed number of EC2 instances programatically and had them utilize their own start up scripts and had those pull work from a SQS queue, so I know I can get something working. Half of my concern is that I'm using the best tool for the job and being cost-efficient in doing so, and that has been harder to decide on given all the tools I could potentially make us of.

Comment: I hear you on the optimization front. And you are spot on that there is a difference between "making it work" and "doing the right thing". There is an intrinsic complexity in trying to map the specific needs/context customers have to the technology options that exist.